# How to analyze chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

There are tools available to analyze the websites like builtwith.com
Can i analyze chrome extensions for the libraries it uses and the other services merged into the extension like google analytics?

Comment: You can write your own tool. Not sure it'll be useful though. I think most programmers find it quite easy and much more reliable to simply look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

All Chrome extensions are HTML /JS and are stored locally so you can generally access the source directly.  Each extension is stored in a sub folder of

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<Name>\Extensions
```

You can find the ID of an extension which is also the name of the sub folder  on Chrome settings

For a more detailed guide:

http://www.labnol.org/software/view-source-of-chrome-extension/21284/

Comment: Is there any faster way then checking the code itself?

Comment: You have the standard tools available for analysing websites and traffic (eg Fiddler) however I've found each one I've looked at to be different. And in a lot of cases using local JSON files rather than a remote db, so whilst looking at the code might be time consuming it's been worthwhile

Comment: The only reason that web service exists is because you can't access source code of a site. Whereas if the extension uses known libraries those will be present in the folder as files.

Comment: This might be useful, called [Tarnish](https://thehackerblog.com/tarnish/#). I am not affiliated with this website.